# Multiple jquery issues in jsp and js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

**jsp**

```
<script src="scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/mp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function() {                                
            setUri();                                
    });
```

here we are calling setUri function , which part of "mp.js" file but unable to access this function if we remove "jquery-2.2.0.js" from this page.

this `hello.jsp` is already working using `"Jquery.js"` but when we want to call `setUri()` then it not calling until we use `"jquery-2.2.0.js"`.

**mp.js**

```
function setUri(pages){
   var objId = document.getElementById('objectId').value;
   uri="https://localhost:7070/test";
   $("#player").attr("src", uri);
}
```

Comment: _Multiple jquery issues in jsp and js_.........  becuase you have more than one jQuery lib.

Comment: Why load two copies of jquery? Is the first one even jquery?

Comment: earlier all functionality working using "jquery.js" , now we have written a new mp.js file and using on jsp and because it not able to use "jquery.js" thats why we placed a new "jquery-2.2.js" file. so how we can solve this.

Comment: My suggestion is not to use both libs jquery1.x  and jquery 2.x

Comment: first check should always be web console errors. post if you see any.

Comment: what happens when you use only `jquery-2.2.0.js` at the top and then simply `mp.js` with no other reference to `jquery.js`?

Comment: Try using `jQuery.noConflict();` before calling any script, See [jQuery Ref](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/). But still it's not recommended.

Comment: You can use jquery-2.2.0.js along with `jquery migrate`.. maybe map.js uses few depreciated functions hence you are facing probs